# how to set up multiple web server avoid conflict port on Windows 7?

Tags: webserver

I tried install Apache (XAMPP) for PHP after that install Tomcat (manually) for Java. Then, running Apache on XAMPP and get the error below.

```
10:15:25 CH  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:15:25 CH  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:15:25 CH  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:15:25 CH  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:15:25 CH  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:15:25 CH  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:15:25 CH  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
Listen 80
```

in *httpd.conf* to some other port. You can find *httpd.conf* in XAMPPs control panel under *Config* -> *Apache (httpd.conf)*

Comment: I replaced it in httpd.conf : Listen 8012 and ServerName localhost:8012.
and I also replaced to httpd-ssl.conf: Listen 444. And it worked.